# How to update a SQL table using average of columns on same row?

Tags: vb.net

I am using the  following SQL statement to update a table with a average of columns in the same row :

```
opdraggem.CommandText = "  Update   SQLTableBlokke    " & _
      "SET blokgemiddeld =  ((tha_min4 +  tha_min3 +tha_min2 +  tha_min1 )/5) "

    opdraggem.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It works, however I suspect it is wrong. How would I get eg. Max or exclude zeros in the calculation?

After much searching I am stumped with what seems a simple action.

Regards

Comment: You're putting in 4 values and dividing by 5

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Is the requirement that you want the average of all non-zero columns?

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Yes that is correct, but I want the average of all non -zero columns across columns for the same row.